# Sweet(-ish) Tripel

Tags: belgian, sweetness

So, I decided to make a Tripel.  I've been brewing for decades, but haven't made a Tripel in about 15 years -- so it's not in my wheel house.

Anyhow, it was a smooth brewday, the stats are as follows...
Grain: 10:1 ratio of Belg. Pilsener to Munich.  With some clear Candi sugar (1#)
OG: 1.080
Mash: 140°F (20 mins), 152°F (75 mins), Mash Out 168°F
Hops: 30 IBUs of Styrian Goldings and Saaz added at various stages
Ferment: Primary: 70°F for 11 days (was 1.016 after primary), Secondary: 14 days at 70°F, Cold Crash: 3 days at 35°F
Yeast: SafAle s-33 Belgian Ale
FG: 1.011 at kegging

So, despite having a low FG (and presumably quite dry with good attenuation), it has a residual sweetness that seems out of character. It's not bad, still pretty yummy, but not the dry, spicy character I'd associate with a Tripel.  Anyone see where I might have gone sideways?  With an FG of 1.011, why would it be sweet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your yeast choice, mash schedule and the simple sugars from candi would make us expect a dry result, which your numbers prove you got. Your 30 IBUs is in the right ballpark to properly balance out the maltiness.

There are certain styles of beer that, while they measure dry, many customers insist that it is sweet (and that they LOVE it). The styles (that I brew and serve) that get these comments on a regular basis are:

- Belgian Dubbel
- Belgian Tripel
- Belgian Quad
- Braggot

What do these all have in common? A sweet adjunct (Belgian candi sugar or honey, in the case of the braggot). And in a big enough dose that you can taste it in the final beer.

My theory is that enough of the candy-character (or honey-character in the case of the braggot) comes through and tricks our brain into thinking we are tasting sweetness.

The candi sugar is very fermentable (all simple sugars) and your numbers prove that the yeast ate all of those actual sugars.

So, what do you do to make your mouth happier with your Tripel? Adjust your recipe next time you brew it! If you want to reduce the perception of sweetness, reduce the candi sugar (or perhaps increase your IBUs). You don't say how much grain you used, so we don't know what fraction of your grain bill is candi sugar.

For reference, my Tripel recipe is 15.6% candi sugar. And that is high enough that many people perceive it as sweet.

Answer (score 0):

There are several factors helping in the sweetness, and they are not what you think they are.

[image: ABV calculation]

These factors are:

- Your addition of Munich
- The high alcohol percentage
- The S-33 yeast
- The actual low IBU

Using Munich yeast gives a nice malty touch, which is somewhat sweet. Alcohol, from 8% ABV onwards, also gives an impression of sweetness. The S-33 yeast also has some by-products (higher alcohols) which can give an extra impression of sweetness. And fourth, 30 IBU is not really much for a good tripel. I suggest, when you redo this brew (the recipe is fine) to go for 40 IBU (Tripel Westmalle has 42 IBU).

Sugar (unless unfermentable complex sugars) completely ferments into alcohol. It does not add sweetness directly, only indirectly through a high level of alcohol.